# How to get the default value after being changed from javascript dom

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js

Is there any sort of way, framework or plugin where I can get the default value of a div after it has been changed from the dom/devTool? For example if `<div class="div-1">Alex</div>` and I use dom/DevTool to change it to `<div class="div-1">Megan</div>`, when I want to get the text of that div how do I get Alex instead of Megan. I am doing ajax so I need the default data instead of the changed data.

Comment: I don't think so, you may prefer to use a data attribute

Comment: your question is too broad. it could be done in a number of ways. if the value is from php, could you save it in a session? or make add a data attribute with the original value and use that

Comment: @Kevin couldn't that still be changed with the development tool?

Comment: Google for Mutation Observer.

Comment: @SangNguyen you mean the data attribute? yes of course, in PHP no, you can't edit the value from dev tools.

Comment: Strong duplicate possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242

Comment: The DOM API doesn't keep of record of all previous states. If you want a record, you have to track that yourself. If I say `someElement.innerHTML = ''`, I lose all data that might have been held in the DOM.